# Performance of Resque jobs

Tags: heroku, resque

My Resque job basically takes params hash and stores it into the DB. In the process it does several reads and writes.

These R/Ws take approx. 5ms in total on my local machine and a little bit more on Heroku (I guess it's because of the shared DB).

However, the rate at which the queue is processed is very low / about 2-3 jobs per second. What could be causing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for a new job, lock a job, do the job, mark it as completed, look for a new job.

You might find that the negotiation to get a new job, accessing Redis etc is causing a lot of overhead. If your task is only 5ms long, it can probably live inside the request-response cycle. Background jobs are great when running a task would extend the response time considerably, very small jobs generally aren't worth the effort involved.

Comment: I have checked the worker logs with VVERBOSE=1 and indeed, you are right.                                                                  ** [14:37:49 2011-06-30] 11420: Checking parameters
** [14:37:50 2011-06-30] 11420: Found job on parameters
** [14:37:50 2011-06-30] 11420: got: (Job{parameters}                         the "powering up" seems to be causing the delay.

Comment: A good question. I haven't used resque/delayed_job enough to fully understand the precise source of the discrepancy between the 1000s of jobs per second in which comparisons are made vs the 1s of jobs per second that are executed on heroku.